# pandas: low level concatenation of DataFrames along axis=1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

The problem:

- one has 2 DataFrames
- one knows that the two have identical (MultiIndex) indices
- (just in case it helps) both indices are sorted
- both DataFrames have columns which do not intersect

How can I concatenate the 2 DataFrames very efficiently by just slapping their memory blocks together, i.e. do equivalent of

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)
```

but forcing somehow to completely disregard index values of both DataFrames to make it very fast? I want it to be essentially as close as possible to a memory copy operation (no merges).

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'i1':['a','a','b','b'], 
                         'i2':[0,1,0,1], 
                         'x':[1.,2.,3.,4.]})
df1.set_index(['i1','i2'], inplace=True)
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'y':[5,6,7,8]}, index=df1.index)

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False)
```

```
         x  y
i1 i2        
a  0   1.0  5
   1   2.0  6
b  0   3.0  7
   1   4.0  8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for col in df2:
    df1[col] = df2[col].values
```